# Vb.Net Object on top of another

Tags: vb.net, object, browser, picturebox

In VB.NET I made a web browser and I wanted there to be an image behind the web browser slightly peeking out. I put the image on after i put the web browser on the form and I cant get it to be behind the browser. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right click the picturebox in the designer and select 'Sent To Back'

Alternatly, right click the webbrowser control an select 'Bring To Front'

Comment: Applies to regular WF controls as well. I couldn't figure out how to stop my calendar control from hiding behind a button. So simple, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be simpler to edit the image to only have the part that is "peeking out" and place that on the form in the appropriate spot?

Comment: But what if someone looks behind the web browser control?  ;)